# Definition of 2NF

Tags: database, database-design

Somewhere the definition of 2NF is given as -

A relation schema R is in 2NF if every nonprime attribute A in R is fully functionally dependent on the primary key of R.

And somewhere it is given as -

A relation schema R is in 2NF if every nonprime attribute A in R is fully functionally dependent on any key of R.

Which is correct ?
Only primary key is to be considered or all the keys are considered when checking partial dependency.

Comment: i think it is any prime key OR equivalently and ALTERNATE key.

Comment: So we can have primary key, candidate key, super keys or foreign keys if any...

Comment: no - not Foreign Keys.  only PK or Alternate Keys (possibly Concatenated keys) etc.

Comment: Neither. "dependent on any" means "dependent on some" not "dependent on all".

Answer (score 0):

> A relation R is in second normal form if every non-prime attribute of R is fully dependent on each candidate key
>   of R.

E.F.Codd, 1971, *Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model*

2NF is not particularly significant. With respect to functional dependencies the normal forms that matter are Elementary Key Normal Form and Boyce-Codd Normal Form.

Comment: It should depend on any candidate key of R instead of each candidate key of R.

Comment: Each and every candidate key, not just one.